# How to send NSString through socket using NSOutputStream

Tags: iphone, ios, sockets

I have to create a chat app for iOS using socket programming and my IP address is `192.168.0.57:9300`.
I have used `Raywenderlich` socket programming example,receiving data working properly but sending not working ,there are no any error or crash.
My code are as follows.

code  for opening streams

```
- (void) initNetworkCommunication {

    CFReadStreamRef readStream;
    CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)@"192.168.0.57", 9300, &readStream, &writeStream);

    inputStream = (NSInputStream *)readStream;
    outputStream = (NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
    [inputStream setDelegate:self];
    [outputStream setDelegate:self];
    [inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [inputStream open];
    [outputStream open];    
}
```

code for sending data

```
- (IBAction)sendMessage:(id)sender
{
        NSString *response  = @"lets start chat";
        NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[response dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
        [outputStream write:[data bytes] maxLength:[data length]]; 
}
```

Delegates

```
- (void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent {

    NSLog(@"stream event %i", streamEvent);

    switch (streamEvent) {

        case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:
            NSLog(@"Stream opened");
            break;
        case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:

            if (theStream == inputStream) {

                uint8_t buffer[1024];
                int len;

                while ([inputStream hasBytesAvailable]) {
                    len = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
                    if (len > 0) {

                        NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:len encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

                        if (nil != output) {

                            NSLog(@"\nreciving data------%@,buffer);

                            [self messageReceived:output];

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            break;


        case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred:

            NSLog(@"Can not connect to the host!");
            break;

        case NSStreamEventEndEncountered:

            [theStream close];
            [theStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
            [theStream release];
            theStream = nil;

            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"Unknown event");
    }

}
Message sending
    - (void) messageReceived:(NSString *)message {

        [self.messages addObject:message];
        [self.tView reloadData];
        NSIndexPath *topIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:messages.count-1 
                                                       inSection:0];
        [self.tView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:topIndexPath 
                          atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle 
                                  animated:YES];

    }
```

please provide me suggestion.

Comment: What do you mean with "it shows the send string"? Does the receiver show it like that? What is the receiver (what Software, post source snippet if possible)? How do you process the received string?

Comment: I have attached all code.server code are written in php

Comment: I used your exact code to initialize a connection and to send network traffic from an iPhone to my Mac. The receiving software is written in Objective C and also using NSStreams. All transmitted strings were OK. I guess your problem might be on the server side (PHP). Have you been able to verify (with another software to send strings) that your server part is working?

Comment: @nullp01nter Hi i am also doing this in android, It is working fine in android using the same Php server

Comment: server side use phpwebsocket code that can be download from here       http://code.google.com/p/php-websocket-server/
  - http://code.google.com/p/php-websocket-server/wiki/Scripting

Comment: Did you get a way out of it I am getting this : server said: :{"type":"usermsg","name":null,"message":null,"color":null}

Comment: In my case code doesn't enters NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable section. What might be reason?

Answer (score 5):

You should add the "\n" at the end of your response like this:

```
- (IBAction)sendMessage:(id)sender
{
        NSString *response  = @"lets start chat\n";
        ////your code
}
```

This work for me, but my problem is that I cannot receive data using the function `(void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent`

Comment: Adding \n doesn't fix it for me. This problem is really bugging me because it's so simple to send the commands in Terminal! My command has quotes in it that I mark with \", so maybe that's a problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem. Got it solved by appending new-line and line-feed character in string.

```
- (IBAction)sendMessage:(id)sender {

        NSString *response  = @"lets start chat\r\n\r\n";
        NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[response dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
        [outputStream write:[data bytes] maxLength:[data length]]; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found writing a separate thread solved this issue for me.
Makes sense as one shouldn't really do network ops on the main thread.
Here is my code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0), ^(void) {
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[response dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
    NSInteger len = [outputStream write:[data bytes] maxLength:[data length]];
    NSLog(@"Len = %ld", len);
});
```

Another point to note is that the NSStreamEventOpenCompleted event is called twice. Once when each of the input and output streams are opened. So one needs to be careful not to write to the output stream prior to its event.